# Do adjectives have gender?

Tags: adjective, gender

I'm trying to get my head around gender in German, for example:

```
Ist Ihr Freund Deutscher?
```

So this is German for "Is your friend German?", referring to a male friend. Now if I wanted to say this for a female, is it:

```
Ist Ihre Freundin Deutscherin?
```

Or...

```
Ist Ihre Freundin Deutscher?
```

Similarly, can I also say:

```
Nein, meine Freundin ist keine Deutscher[in].
```

I guess the question is whether or not adjectives take the same female ending 'in' as nouns do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all the word *Deutscher* in the sentence

> Ist Ihr Freund (ein) Deutscher?

is a noun and not an adjective.* The proper female version would then be

> Ist Ihre Freundin (eine) Deutsche?

When using an adjective you'd say

> Ist Ihr Freund deutsch? / Ist Ihre Freundin deutsch?

So in this case the word doesn't change. However compare the following:

> ein deutscher Freund / eine deutsche Freundin

---

* To be frank one could construct a context where it could be used as an adjective but it's still written lowercase:

> Mein Freund ist ein englischer Held. Ist Ihr Freund ein deutscher (Held)?

Answer (score 6):

Deutsche/r/n/m are nounified adjectives. The ending depends on the ending of the adjective which depends on the gender and the preceding article which may be definite or indefinite... in your case it is indefinite as musiKk pointed out ... *eine/r/m/n*

So you have to apply the very same rules as if you were to say:

> eine *schöne* Frau

Example:

> Eisbein ist ein deutsches Gericht.
>
> Was willst du essen? Keine Ahnung, was Deutsches.
>
> Den deutschen Schülern machen Hausaufgaben Spaß.
>
> Die Hausaufgaben werden von den Deutschen gemacht.

Comment: Dativ vs. Akkusativ? *Wem* machen die Hausaufgaben Spaß?

Comment: sorry I forgot the n at Schüler... in both cases it is dativ

Comment: @Emanuel You wrote "Das Auto ist ein Deutsches.". In fact, "... ist ein deutsches." is ellipsis for "... ist ein deutsches Auto.". Leaving out "Auto" does not turn the adjective into a noun.

Comment: @Eugene... you're right. I changed the example :)

Comment: Das neue Beispiel ist gut; das mit den Schülern klingt übrigens so, als wenn die Deutschen die Deppen sind und für die Anderen die Hausaufgaben erledigen :D .... Wofür ist eigentlich der Downvote, doch nicht etwa wegen den Beispielen?

Comment: Downvote removed, as Emanuel has now edited his Answer. I think what would help OP would be a link to a reference that spells out the grammar in exhaustive detail. Does anyone know of such a link?

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=deutsch&features=%28Cat+A%29&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive&lang=en

Comment: Was genau meinst du @EugeneSeidel. Wie man ein *nomifiziertes* Adjektiv behandelt?

Comment: Thank you Takkat, a very good page. What I'm also curious to know is this. musikk wrote, "When using an adjective you'd say 'Ist Ihr Freund deutsch? / Ist Ihre Freundin deutsch?' So in this case the word doesn't change." I believe that language learners find this confusing. Is there a reference that gives an explicit rule for determining when the adjective takes the gender of the noun... and when it doesn't? I must shamefacedly confess that I would find it difficult to express such a rule.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Not perfectly matching, but the simple way as you learn in school: *Wie ist dein Freund - Mein Freund ist deutsch* vs *Was ist dein Freund - Mein Freund ist (ein) Deutscher*, and yes, though, it sounds strange asking *Wie* for being German. ... http://www.schulelaupen.ch/grossklein.htm ... btw. for more discussion, I recommend chat

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the question in the headline:

No, adjectives do not have a gender. But they adapt to the gender of the noun they refer to(*):

> Ein **deutscher** Freund. Eine **deutsche** Freundin. Ein **deutsches** Mädchen.

In your case, as both other answers already pointed out, it is a conversion from adjective to noun. Since the word isn't an adjective any more but a noun it needs an article. You take the article of the omitted noun:

> Der Deutsche <sub>(Freund)</sub>. Die Deutsche <sub>(Freundin)</sub>. Das Deutsche <sub>(Mädchen)</sub>.

---

(*) Note: The adjective adapts not only to the gender itself. The case (nominative, genitive, dative, accusative) and the number (singular or plural) are also important:

> *den deutschen Freundinnen* <sup>dative plural</sup>

Answer (score 0):

"Markus ist Deutscher" follows the same pattern as "Markus ist Maler" (Markus is a painter) or "Markus ist Bauer" (Markus is a farmer). So "Deutscher" is not an adjective, but a noun, and nouns have a gender. And nouns are written with uppercase first letter, which is not true for adjectives.

You can also use this examples with an article: "Markus ist ein Deutscher", "Markus ist ein Maler" or "Markus ist ein Bauer".

And these are the female forms: "Maria ist (eine) Deutsche", "Maria ist (eine) Malerin" or "Maria ist (eine) Bäuerin".

Of course, "deutscher" can also be an adjective: "Markus ist ein deutscher Maler" (Markus is a German painter). "Maria ist eine deutsche Bäuerin" (Maria is a German farmer).